# wxFileDialog::GetPath() returning "/" on Ubuntu, fine on Windows

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
wxFileDialog* ctrl = new wxFileDialog(this, L"Open", "/home/example", "example.test",       "|All files (*.*)|*.*", wxFD_OPEN | wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST, wxDefaultPosition);
if(ctrl->ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
{
      ctrl->GetPath().wx_str()); // = '/'
}

ctrl->Destroy();
```

No matter what I do, I'm always getting "/", a forward slash, from ctrl->GetPath().

Any idea why?

Comment: The string `"|All files (*.*)|*.*", ` should be `"All files (*.*)|*.*", ` i.e. the first vertical bar shouldn't be there.